# Print a linkedlist

Tags: c++, linked-list

Given the name of a node, this function should search the linked list; if its found inside, then return a pointer that points to that node, otherwise return null. Note: I am certain I have written this function successfully.

```
// getNode

Node *LinkedList::getNode(string name)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->name.compare(name) == 0)
            return temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Given a node, this function prints: teamName(winScore-loseScore) on screen. Examples: UCLA(25-13) or Texas A&M(31-25). Note: I am sure I have written this function successfully.

```
// printNode

void LinkedList::printNode(Node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    else {
        cout << node->name << "(" << node->winScore;
        cout << "-" << node->loseScore << ")";
    }
}
```

Given a team name, this function is supposed to print all the nodes in its adjacency list one-by-one in the following format (NOTE: the following is just one example!) This is where I think I am wrong.

```
Missouri University beat: New Mexico(52-23), Salisbury (48-31), Virginia (34-9)

void LinkedList::printList(string name)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        cout << "\n Empty list" << endl;
    else {

        Node *temp = head; 
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << temp->name << " beat: " << temp->name << endl; // Is this right?
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you're wrong? What is happening and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: `cout << temp->name << " beat: " << temp->name << endl` looks a lot like you're printing the same thing twice.

Comment: @scohe001 I can't get it to print two teams names. My code in printList functions ends up printing Mssouri University beat: Missouri University(52-23)

Comment: An no point does `printList` use `name`

Comment: @user4581301 exactly how do I get it to print the next universities name?

Comment: Looks like you want `cout << name << " beat: " << temp->name << endl`, but without a [mcve] no one can be sure.

Comment: You're going to find that the hard part of this assignment is not printing a `','` after the last item on the list.

Comment: This won't solve your problem but since you're only checking for equality I suggest replacing `if (temp->name.compare(name) == 0)` with `if (temp->name==name)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is close to what you want:

```
void LinkedList::printList(string name)
{
    // find the node for the name you supply
    // (or else I don't understand why 'name' is supplied to this function)

    Node *temp = getNode(name);

    if (temp) {                     // node with name found           
        if (temp->next) {           // there's at least one adjacent node
            cout << temp->name << " beat: ";
            while ((temp = temp->next) != nullptr) {
                printNode(temp); 
                if (temp->next) cout << ", ";
            };
            cout << "\n";
        } else {                    // no adjacent nodes
            cout << temp->name << " did not beat anyone\n";
        }
    }
}
```